# Install gulp in angular2-meteor app

Tags: meteor, typescript, gulp, angular, angular2-meteor

Thanks in advance.
I am making an *Angular2-meteor* app. In the app I want to use *Gulp* in *Angular2-meteor* to minify and compile typscript code,but I cant install *gulp package*. Can u help me please and thank you.

Comment: Could u attach error log or something?

Comment: the problem that I can not find the installation method gulp a meteor-angular2 project

Answer (score 0):

Meteor compiles all for you, you don't need it.

If you need a production bundle just run `meteor build <output path>` in the project folder.